# Why carriage return not rendered as a line break when assigned to textContent although formatted using pre?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm confused about the rendering behavior of a string assigned to `textContent` when it contains a `\r` vs `\n`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) says:

> The textContent property of the Node interface represents the text
>   content of the node and its descendants.

Then why does a `textContent`'s text which contains a `\r` and whose applied a `pre` isn't rendered with line brakes, while `\n` does?

```js
var textWithCR = "line1\rline2\r";
document.getElementById('crWithTextContent').textContent = textWithCR;
document.getElementById('crWithInnerHTML').innerHTML = textWithCR;
document.getElementById('crWithInnerText').innerText = textWithCR;
  
var textWithLF = "line3\nline4\n";
document.getElementById('lfWithTextContent').textContent = textWithLF;
document.getElementById('lfWithInnerHTML').innerHTML = textWithLF;
document.getElementById('lfWithInnerText').innerText = textWithLF;
```

```css
.formatted {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="crWithTextContent" class="formatted"></div><br/>
<div id="crWithInnerHTML" class="formatted"></div><br/>
<div id="crWithInnerText" class="formatted"></div><br/>

<div id="lfWithTextContent" class="formatted"></div><br/>
<div id="lfWithInnerHTML" class="formatted"></div><br/>
<div id="lfWithInnerText" class="formatted"></div>
```

I also looked at the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent), which says:

> This attribute returns the text content of this node and its
>   descendants. [...]
>   On getting, no serialization is performed, the
>   returned string does not contain any markup.
>   No whitespace normalization is performed and the returned string does not contain
>   the white spaces in element content [...]

Well, if "the returned string does not contain the white spaces in element content", then why does it seems that in the following code `\n` exists when we get `textContent` (by printing it on console), while `\r` doesn't?

```js
var textWithCR = "line1\rline2\r";
document.getElementById('crWithTextContent').textContent = textWithCR;
var textWithLF = "line3\nline4\n";
document.getElementById('lfWithTextContent').textContent = textWithLF;

console.log(document.getElementById('crWithTextContent').textContent);
console.log(document.getElementById('lfWithTextContent').textContent);
```

```css
.formatted {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="crWithTextContent" class="formatted"></div><br/>
<div id="lfWithTextContent" class="formatted"></div>
```

What's the reason for this `textContent` behavior when it contains a `\r`?

Comment: For one, no modern OS uses only `\r` as a linebreak.

Comment: @jhpratt, I'm querying Windows Event Viewer, which in my case has many events with only `\r`s as line breaks.

Comment: @HeyJude Windows uses `\r\n`. I don't use Windows, but I imagine nothing would produce _solely_ `\r`.

Comment: @jhpratt, surprising, but true. I'll upload an image when I'll get back to it.

Comment: @HeyJude In the console a lot of program use `\r` to overwrite the current line since it does a carriage return (puts the cursor at the start of the line) without a line break (move the cursor to  a new line).

Comment: @jhpratt, I looked at it further, and it turns out we had code that was incorrectly logging `\r` solely. Augh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\r` (U+000D CR) is there at index 5:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('test');
elem.textContent = "line1\rline2\r";

console.log( elem.textContent );
console.log( elem.textContent.charCodeAt( 5 ) ); // 13
console.log( "\r".charCodeAt( 0 ) ); // same char
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

The problem you are facing is that CSS doesn't define U+000D CR as a [segment-break](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#segment-break), and nor does HTML.

HTML when it [normalizes newlines](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#normalize-newlines) will convert all `\r\n` sequences to `\n` and then all remaining `\r` to `\n`, so effectively getting rid of all lonely `\r` characters. However, `Node.textContent` doesn't call this *normalize-newlines* algorithm, so they're not converted to `\n` and not interpreted as *segment-break*.

For this to happen, you would need to set your element's content by an other mean which will call this algorithm, but doing so, you will loose your original data.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('test');
elem.innerHTML = "line1\rline2\r";

console.log( elem.textContent );
console.log( elem.textContent.charCodeAt( 5 ) ); // converted to \n (U+000A  => 10)
```

```css
#test { white-space: pre-wrap }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```